# Filepicker can`t see other media except images/videos

Tags: android, filepicker

I'm planning on creating an android app that will send sms using SEND_SMS, successful but I don't want the phone numbers to be hardcoded on the app. Tried using file pickers to read and parse sheets/xlsx/txt files but nothing works(can only see images). Tried looking at google sheets API but there are no sample projects and the documentation only covers dependencies.
This is the latest filepicker that works for me but only shows images(from filepicker master)

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jaiselrahman.filepickersample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.jaiselrahman.filepickersample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.activity.DirSelectActivity;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.activity.FilePickerActivity;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.activity.PickFile;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.config.Configurations;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.model.MediaFile;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.utils.FilePickerProvider;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static int FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FileListAdapter fileListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MediaFile> mediaFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.file_list);
        fileListAdapter = new FileListAdapter(mediaFiles);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(fileListAdapter);

        final ActivityResultLauncher<Configurations> pickImage = registerForActivityResult(new PickFile().throughDir(true), new ActivityResultCallback<List<MediaFile>>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(List<MediaFile> result) {
                if (result != null)
                    setMediaFiles(result);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.launch_imagePicker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickImage.launch(new Configurations.Builder()
                        .setCheckPermission(true)
                        .setSelectedMediaFiles(mediaFiles)
                        .enableImageCapture(true)
                        .setShowVideos(false)
                        .setSkipZeroSizeFiles(true)
                        .setMaxSelection(10)
                        .build());
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.launch_videoPicker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilePickerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.CONFIGS, new Configurations.Builder()
                        .setCheckPermission(true)
                        .setSelectedMediaFiles(mediaFiles)
                        .enableVideoCapture(true)
                        .setShowImages(false)
                        .setMaxSelection(10)
                        .setIgnorePaths(".*WhatsApp.*")
                        .build());
                startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.launch_audioPicker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilePickerActivity.class);
                MediaFile file = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < mediaFiles.size(); i++) {
                    if (mediaFiles.get(i).getMediaType() == MediaFile.TYPE_AUDIO) {
                        file = mediaFiles.get(i);
                    }
                }
                intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.CONFIGS, new Configurations.Builder()
                        .setCheckPermission(true)
                        .setShowImages(false)
                        .setShowVideos(false)
                        .setShowAudios(true)
                        .setSingleChoiceMode(true)
                        .setSelectedMediaFile(file)
                        .setTitle("Select an audio")
                        .build());
                startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.launch_filePicker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DirSelectActivity.CONFIGS, new Configurations.Builder()
                        .setCheckPermission(true)
                        .setSelectedMediaFiles(mediaFiles)
                        .setShowFiles(true)
                        .setShowImages(true)
                        .setShowAudios(true)
                        .setShowVideos(true)
                        .setIgnoreNoMedia(false)
                        .enableVideoCapture(true)
                        .enableImageCapture(true)
                        .setIgnoreHiddenFile(false)
                        .setMaxSelection(10)
                        .setTitle("Select a file")
                        .build());
                startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILE_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null) {
            List<MediaFile> mediaFiles = data.<MediaFile>getParcelableArrayListExtra(FilePickerActivity.MEDIA_FILES);
            if(mediaFiles != null) {
                setMediaFiles(mediaFiles);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setMediaFiles(List<MediaFile> mediaFiles) {
        this.mediaFiles.clear();
        this.mediaFiles.addAll(mediaFiles);
        fileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share_log) {
            shareLogFile();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void shareLogFile() {
        File logFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "logcat.txt");
        try {
            if (logFile.exists())
                logFile.delete();
            logFile.createNewFile();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -t 100 *:W Glide:S " + FilePickerActivity.TAG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (logFile.exists()) {
            Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intentShareFile.setType("text/plain");
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    FilePickerProvider.getUriForFile(this, logFile));
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FilePicker Log File");
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "FilePicker Log File");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share"));
        }
    }
}
```

FileListAdapter

```
package com.jaiselrahman.filepickersample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.jaiselrahman.filepicker.model.MediaFile;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<MediaFile> mediaFiles;

    public FileListAdapter(ArrayList<MediaFile> mediaFiles) {
        this.mediaFiles = mediaFiles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.file_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MediaFile mediaFile = mediaFiles.get(position);
        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
        holder.filePath.setText(context.getString(R.string.uri, mediaFile.getUri()));
        holder.fileMime.setText(context.getString(R.string.mime, mediaFile.getMimeType()));
        holder.fileSize.setText(context.getString(R.string.size, mediaFile.getSize()));
        holder.fileBucketName.setText(context.getString(R.string.bucketname, mediaFile.getBucketName()));
        if (mediaFile.getMediaType() == MediaFile.TYPE_IMAGE
                || mediaFile.getMediaType() == MediaFile.TYPE_VIDEO) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(mediaFile.getUri())
                    .into(holder.fileThumbnail);
        } else if (mediaFile.getMediaType() == MediaFile.TYPE_AUDIO) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(mediaFile.getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_audio)
                    .into(holder.fileThumbnail);
        } else {
            holder.fileThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mediaFiles.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView fileThumbnail;
        private TextView filePath, fileSize, fileMime, fileBucketName;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            fileThumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.file_thumbnail);
            filePath = view.findViewById(R.id.file_path);
            fileSize = view.findViewById(R.id.file_size);
            fileMime = view.findViewById(R.id.file_mime);
            fileBucketName = view.findViewById(R.id.file_bucketname);
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            File propertiesFile = project.rootProject.file('app/gradle.properties')
            if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
                properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
                storeFile file(properties.getProperty('KEYSTORE_FILE'))
                keyAlias properties.getProperty('KEY_ALIAS')
                storePassword properties.getProperty('KEYSTORE_PASSWORD')
                keyPassword properties.getProperty('KEY_PASSWORD')
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jaiselrahman.filepickersample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    implementation project(':filepicker')
}
```

Comment: There is ACTION_PICK, ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to pick a file. And what are you doing?

Comment: can you please be more understandable for a newb. sorry

Comment: I did not understand you either as you did not tell what you used to pick a file. The three actions i mentioned are normally used to pick a file. So if you use something different then please explain why you would.

Comment: honestly i do not understand most of it, i got that sample code from here https://github.com/jaiselrahman/FilePicker, they said that i can pick most file types (images, vids, docs) but i only see images and videos from the storage. everything works except that i cannot see docs files which it should be. thanks anyways

Comment: But... tell why you use that file picker library? I still dont know as you still did not tell. Which reason? And why not the three actions i mentioned? And you did not tell in your post that you used an external file picker and of course you should have started your post with mentioning that.

Comment: `they said that i can pick most file types` Well that is ridiculous to begin with as a file picker can pick all files normally.